# fail get download url from firebase(database)

Tags: android, json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I do i [simple](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/upload-files) example to upload file to *firebase*. After download i push download sting file to database. When i do it from debagger all fine.When i just launch app file will be upload but i don't have download url in my database.

Launch download method in `onClick` and after push into database:

```
  public void button_click(){
    auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    FirebaseUser user = auth.getCurrentUser();
    if (user != null) {
        // User is signed in
        String temp = upload(user);
        //temp = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child("User: "+user.getUid()+"/"+"img.jpg").getDownloadUrl().toString();

        GPSTracker gps = new GPSTracker(this);
        double latitude = gps.getLatitude();
        double longitude = gps.getLongitude();

        database =  FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference(user.getUid());
        Map<String, User> users = new HashMap<String, User>();
        users.put("User data: " , new User(String.valueOf(latitude)+"/"+String.valueOf(longitude),temp));
        myRef.setValue(users);

       // Intent i = new Intent(CameraFoto.this, pc.dd.sex_startup.LogIn.Maps.Map.class);
       // startActivity(i);
       // finish();
    } else {
        // No user is signed in
    }
}
```

Upload method(see `onSuccess`):

```
 public String upload (FirebaseUser user){
    final String[] dwndurl = new String[1];
    // File or Blob
    Uri file = Uri.fromFile(new File("/storage/emulated/0/VK/img.jpg"));// Create the file metadata
    StorageMetadata  metadata = new StorageMetadata.Builder()
            .setContentType("image/jpeg")
            .build();
    //get storage
    FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();// Create a storage reference from our app
    StorageReference storageRef = storage.getReferenceFromUrl("gs://sexstartup-e3a65.appspot.com");// Upload file and metadata to the path 'images/mountains.jpg'
    UploadTask  uploadTask = storageRef.child("User: "+user.getUid()+"/"+file.getLastPathSegment()).putFile(file, metadata);// Listen for state changes, errors, and completion of the upload.
    uploadTask.addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onProgress(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
            int progress = (int) ((100 * taskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred()) / taskSnapshot.getTotalByteCount());
            ProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.upload_progress);
            progressBar.setProgress(progress);
            System.out.println("Upload is " + progress + "% done");
            Log.d("---","Upload is " + progress + "% done");
        }
    }).addOnPausedListener(new OnPausedListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onPaused(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
            System.out.println("Upload is paused");
        }
    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
            // Handle unsuccessful uploads
            Log.d("---","Upload false " + exception.getMessage());

        }
    }).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
            // Handle successful uploads on complete
            Uri downloadUrl = null;
            do{
                downloadUrl = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();
                dwndurl[0] = downloadUrl.toString();
                    }
            while (dwndurl[0]==null);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Upload done",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });

    return dwndurl[0];
}}
```

Json in Firebase database when dubbug app:

```
{
"2Yrkr7YWqHYm1Yzg9NHpDcXDz2N2" : {
"User data: " : {
  "lat" : "47.8405892/35.1428222",
  "url" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/sexstartup-e3a65.appspot.com/o/User%3A+2Yrkr7YWqHYm1Yzg9NHpDcXDz2N2%2Fimg.jpg?alt=media&token=dfefa9cd-89e7-4cf2-980c-c45bad3d39a5"
} },
```

Json in Firebase database when just launch app:

```
{
"2Yrkr7YWqHYm1Yzg9NHpDcXDz2N2" : {
"User data: " : {
  "lat" : "47.8405892/35.1428222",
} },
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got ya..

You are expecting this:

```
{
"2Yrkr7YWqHYm1Yzg9NHpDcXDz2N2" : {
"User data: " : {
  "lat" : "47.8405892/35.1428222",
  "url" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/sexstartup-e3a65.appspot.com/o/User%3A+2Yrkr7YWqHYm1Yzg9NHpDcXDz2N2%2Fimg.jpg?alt=media&token=dfefa9cd-89e7-4cf2-980c-c45bad3d39a5"
} },
```

But getting this:

```
{
"2Yrkr7YWqHYm1Yzg9NHpDcXDz2N2" : {
"User data: " : {
  "lat" : "47.8405892/35.1428222",
} },
```

**Reason:** Your upload task is asynchronous. Your upload task begins and code execution moves to next statement. i.e. `return dwndurl[0];`. As a result, it will return `null`.

Hence, your temp in `String temp = upload(user);` will be `null`. And from the issue you are facing, it can be confirmed that `null` values are never stored. Even, their keys won't exist in the database structure.

This is what I have understood.

Comment: i understatd this, so i add `while`

Comment: @Daggydag13 this won't make any difference.

Comment: so how sinhronize it?

Comment: @Daggydag13 hehehe... Think another way.. just move your code from `GPSTracker gps = new GPSTracker(this);` to `myRef.setValue(users);` to your upload task success Listener

Answer (score 0):

I have also faced this problem so what you have to do is:

Go to the Firebase database then select the rules tab which showing on top then set that read and write true.

{

"rules": {

```
".read": "true",
".write": "true"
```

}

}

I hope it will help you.:)